# how to Zip files in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, file, zip

How to zip files(Any files or folder ) in vb.net 2005?

Answer (score 16):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) is an easy-to-use, free, open-source library for handling ZIP files in VB.NET and other .NET languages.

Some sample VB.NET code, to create a zip file, adding files one at a time:

```
Dim ZipToCreate As String = "ex1.zip"
Dim DirectoryToZip As String = "c:\temp"
Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    Dim filenames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip)
    Dim filename As String
    For Each filename In filenames
        zip.AddFile(filename)
    Next
    zip.Save(ZipToCreate)
End Using
```

Or, add files in a group:

```
Dim ZipToCreate As String = "ex1.zip"
Dim DirectoryToZip As String = "c:\temp"
Dim filenames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip)
Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    zip.AddFiles(filenames, "temp")
    zip.Save(ZipToCreate)
End Using
```

or, Code to zip up an entire directory or folder:

```
Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    zip.AddDirectory(directory)
    zip.Save(targetZip)
End Using
```

Code to extract a zip file:

```
    Dim ZipFileToExtract As String = "c:\foo.zip"
    Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipFileToExtract)
        Dim e As ZipEntry
        For Each e In zip
            ' can conditionally extract here, '
            ' based on name, size, date, whatever.'
            e.Extract
        Next
    End Using
```

Extract with a progress bar:

```
Imports Ionic.Zip

Module SimpleUnzip
  Public Sub Unzip(ByVal ZipToUnpack As String, ByVal ExtractDirectory As String)
    Try
      Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Maximum = zip.Entries.Count
        Dim entry As ZipEntry
        For Each entry In zip
            Form1.Label1.Text = entry.FileName
            entry.Extract(ExtractDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = Form1.ProgressBar1.Value + 1
            ' sleep because it's too fast otherwise.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Next
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Form1.Label1.Text = "Done"
      End Using
    Catch ex1 As Exception
      Form1.Label1.Text = ("Exception: " & ex1.ToString())
    End Try
  End Sub
End Module
```

DotNetZip has progress events for reading, saving, or extracting, so you can power progress bars in ASP.NET or Windows Forms.  It does password-protected zip files, Unicode, ZIP64, and self-extracting archives. The zip files it produces are compatible with all other zip tools - WinZip, WinRAR, Windows Explorer, Pkunzip, etc.  There's a good help file ([online version here](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/frames.htm)) with tons of code examples.  There are [samples available for download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DotNetZip), too.

Comment: I've always used SharpZipLib in the past, but I've just tried DotNetZip, and it is AWESOME. Far easier to use, and took me minutes to set up. Thanks Cheeso!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

Comment: DotNetZip is actively being improved on CodePlex, and simplifies some methods over SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to program in VB.NET. However, a search revealed an interesting link: [Zip Compression VB.NET Examples](http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/zip.asp). I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: NB: The examples rely on the commercial Chilkat ZIP library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ICSharCode's](http://www.icsharpcode.net/) [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our [Rebex ZIP](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/) component.

Here are some samples of operations you are asking for:

Simple zipping files in one line of code:

```
' add content of the local directory C:\Data\  '
' to the directory \Data-2010 (within the ZIP archive) '
' (ZIP archive C:\archive.zip doesn't have to exist) 
ZipArchive.Add("C:\archive.zip", "C:\Data\*", "\Data-2010")
```

Simple unzipping in one line of code:

```
' extract all *.TXT files from the directory \Data-2010 (within the ZIP file) '
' to the existing local directory C:\Data '
ZipArchive.Extract("C:\archive.zip", "\Data-2010\*.html", "C:\Data")
```

More samples can be found [here](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/tutorials.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Shell it, wa-la done in two lines

```
Dim zipcmd as String = "zip -r C:\directory\of\my\folder C:\directory\of\my\zip"
Shell("cmd.exe /c" + zipcmd1, AppWinStyle.Hide, True)
```