# VB.Net 4.6 using Zipfile

Tags: vb.net, winforms, zip

I have been searching this site for a while and cant seem to find a solution. I am trying to to use ZipFile to zip some PDFs from my directory but whenever I type `Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile` I get errors saying:

> 'Using' operand of type 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile' must implement 'System.IDisposable'
>
> 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile' has no constructors.

After searching through this site I found out I had to add some references which I did I added: `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.Filesystem` then I made sure I am using the correct .Net framework and I am using .NET 4.6 in VS 2013. I am stuck on what to do, all I wanted was to zip several files from a folder, but I can't use `ZipFile`. Any information on where to look into this is greatly appreciated.

The code I am using is:

```
Dim ZipToCreate As String = "ex1.zip"
Dim DirectoryToZip As String = "c:\temp"
Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    Dim filenames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip)
    Dim filename As String
    For Each filename In filenames
        zip.AddFile(filename)
    Next
    zip.Save(ZipToCreate)
End Using
```

from this example -> [how to Zip files in vb.net 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906354/how-to-zip-files-in-vb-net-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up 2 different "ZipFile" APIs.

The sample code you copied from expects you to have a reference to the [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library to use the `ZipFile` class, which is not part of the .NET Framework.

The .NET Framework itself also has a `ZipFile` class, but with a different API, and that's the one your code is currently referring to.

Pick which one you want to use and make sure you reference the correct libraries and read the appropriate documentation to code with it properly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am still a beginner with vb so I am sorry if this is a dumb question: so if I want to reference DotNetZip I would just have to download it correct? and when you say different API how would I know which .NET uses?

Comment: Yes, you have to download it, or get it on NuGet if it's available there.  As for different API, I wasn't talking about the .NET version, which I don't think is relevant if you'll be using `DotNetZip`.  By different APIs, I was only saying that the built-in .NET Framework `ZipFile` class doesn't have the same methods as the `ZipFile` defined in the `DotNetZip` library, so obviously, you can't use them the same way. The class names are the same, but they are actually very different.

Comment: That makes sense thank you so much! So if I download it and use it in my visual studio would someone else be able to use my project on theirs if they dont have dotnetzip installed? Because I am building this and want to add it to the main server but i dont know if someone else would be able to use it, I want to confirm your reply as the answer I do that by just checking the check mark correct? thank you again

Comment: The other people would need to have the DotNetZip library on their machines too. Alternatively, if you are not interested in dealing with third party libraries, investigate how to use the built-in zipping library in the .NET Framework.  It's pretty nice too.

Answer (score 0):

The errors clearly say that you can't use `Using` with a class that doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and that you cant create an instance of `ZipFile` because it has no constructors. If you read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see that the `ZipFile` class only has static methods. They was to zip all the files in `DirectoryToZip` into a zip file called `ZipToCreate` is:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectoryToZip, ZipToCreate)
```